# Django redirecting to a different view in another app

Tags: django

There are many similar questions to mine on Stack Overflow, but none which solve my problem.

I have a class-based view which accepts files, and once a valid file is found, I would like the website to redirect the user to a template inside a different app, passing in some parameters.

I've seen others put an extra path in 'urlpatterns' and get the view from there. But doing this only makes a GET signal on my command prompt, but not actually changing the web url.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect   # used to render templates
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views import View

from .forms import UploadForm
from .models import FileUpload

class UploadView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        files_list = FileUpload.objects.all()
        return render(self.request, 'upload/upload.html', {'csv_files': files_list})

def post(self, request):
    form = UploadForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        csv_file = form.save()
        data = {'is_valid': True,
                'name': csv_file.file.name,
                'url': csv_file.file.url,
                'date': csv_file.uploaded_at}
        # REDIRECT USER TO VIEW PASSING 'data' IN CONTEXT
        return redirect('graph:chart', file_url=csv_file.file.url)
    else:
        data = {'is_valid': False}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "upload"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.UploadView.as_view(), name='drag_and_drop'),
]
```

urls.py (of other app)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "graph"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.page, name='chart'),
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify an app name and use exactly the `redirect` shortcut as you started:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns

in the other app `urls.py` define `app_name = 'other_app'`, and then use `redirect('other_app:url_name', parameter1=p1, parameter2 = p2)`

you can name easily your parameters either using `path` (Django >=2.0) or `url` (`re_path` for Django >=2.0), for instance:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/<int:year>/<int:month>/<slug:slug>/', views.article_detail),
    re_path(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
]
```

Comment: I have added app_name = "graph" and changed the redirect url in views.py (see question edit). I am confused about which urls.py I must edit and what view it must use?

Comment: your inputs are correct, what should be corrected is the way you pass the file reference to your other view. It seems you upload a file in the first view through a ModelForm. Then you should pass a reference to the object you saved in your database, rather than the url of the file (redirect can't be use to post data). 
In the other apps urls.py file edit:
`path('<int:file_id>', views.page, name='chart')`
and then:
`redirect('graph:chart', file_id=csv_file.id)`
edit your view function to retrieve the objects through its primary keyt:
`def page(request, file_id):`